# Single line comments in Ansi-C

Tags: c, gcc

I'm used to `//` to mark a single line comment from Java and Visual Studio and was surprised that this does not exist for Ansi-C. Using `/* my comment */`is quite annoying. Is there any other way to mark a single line comment when using Ansi-C?

Comment: Would be nice if people explained why they downvote...

Comment: The reason for down vote is probably because you are asking a question which can easily be resolved on google.  that a particular commenting style doesn't exist in ANSI-C is one thing to express annoyance is another.  Mixing comment styles is a bad habit /* just saying */

Comment: Well, it's true that one can find out easily that Ansi-C does not have a special syntax for single line comments, but I was asking about alternatives.

Comment: :-) you can always switch to c99 standard which supports it, and voila annoyance gone

Answer (score 33, accepted):

ANSI-C, no, but the current standard revision allows them, and has done so ever since C99.

Comment: After a recent bump, I though I would just add - I don't like using C++ `//` comments in C99, C11, etc. Straight away, I grok what I'm dealing with: "It's a C file". It's never caused me any problems. This is a purely personal preference though. Also, `//` comments don't work in macros - and I'm not looking for a macro vs, inline argument here.

Answer (score 9):

You could also write a macro:

```
#define COMMENT(x)

int main() {
   COMMENT(Hi there)
   return 0;
}
```

Other than that nothing obvious in ANSI C - you're correct in noting that `/* */` style is not valid in ANSI C 89

Comment: The macro has the downside that your comment can't contain commas unless you wrap it in parantheses (as in `COMMENT((Hi, there))`)

Comment: @caf - agreed - I don't think it actually wins you anything over simply typing `/* */`

Comment: @awoodland: I prefer the `//`syntax for commenting out code because you only need to type at the beginning of the line. Writing `COMMENT(`and a closing bracket at the end won't improve this at all.

Comment: What's the advantage of such comment over traditional one?

Answer (score 7):

Well ...

ANSI C is C99; and it allows comments starting with `//` extending to the end of the line.
In the previously published standard (C89/C90) the `//` comments weren't described (but many compilers accepted them as an extra anyway).

You have yet another option for commenting: the `#if 0` / `#endif` construction (usually used for commenting out "inactive" code)

```
/* ... */
#if 0
This is a comment
#endif
/* ... */
```

Comment: It gets a little clearer now. I was using the -pedantic option, which enforces strict ISO C and not only ANSI-C. Is it correct to say that `//` is allowed in ASNI-C (C99), but not in strict ISO C?

Comment: With `gcc`, using `gcc -ansi -pedantic ...` is the same (for now) as `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic ...`. To use `gcc` in Standards-conforming mode with C99 (as far as it goes), try `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic ...`

Comment: thanks for clarifying! So there is the different versions of C - C89, C99 and C11. At least the first two are also standardized as ANSI-C and ISO-C, which is not the same, right?

Comment: ANSI-C, or ISO-C, are the same thing (one is published by ANSI: *American National Standards Institute*, the other by ISO: *International Organization for Standardization*). There was a C Standard published by ANSI in 1989 (and by ISO in 1990), which was replaced by the 1999 Standard (both organizations) which will be replaced by the next Standard. A draft of the current Standard is freely available at http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf. The draft of the upcoming Standard is at http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf

Comment: Ok, I got it. But why is gcc still interpreting -ansi as C89 if there is another ANSI standard (C99)?

Comment: Because gcc does not (yet) fully conform to the C99 Standard: see http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html

Comment: [ANSI sells the Standard](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ISO/IEC+9899:1999) for USD 403; [ISO sells it](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=29237) for CHF 352.

Comment: thanks a lot for all your answers. Being a student, I can*t really afford to buy the standard though ;)

Comment: @mort: the freely available n1256.pdf draft is just like the Standard proper -- apparently even gcc programmers use the draft :-)

Answer (score 4):

Sorry but it looks like in ANSI-C only `/* comment */` are used. 
http://members.cox.net/midian/articles/ansic1.htm