# Can Someone please describe the process that happens in this code(line by line)?

Tags: java, character, literals

```
class Example{
public static void main(String args[]){
char a='a';
System.out.println(a=='\u0061');
System.out.println(\u0061=='\u0061');
System.out.println(\u0061==97);
\u0061='\u0041';
System.out.println('A'=='\u0041');
System.out.println(65=='\u0041');
System.out.println(65==a);
System.out.println('\u0041'==a);        
}
}
```

Output : true*7

I can't understand this code. Please help

Comment: If you replace every occurrence of `\u0061` in your code with `a`, and `\u0041` with `A`, it might make more sense to you.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Try it. You might be surprised.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. `char a='a';` - variable `a` stores a lowercase a character
2. `System.out.println(a=='\u0061');` - in UTF lowercase a character is represented as [\u0061](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061/index.htm)
3. `System.out.println(\u0061=='\u0061');` - `\u0061` value is unquoted so it's [decoded into lowercase a during compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30727799/1602555) making it `a=='\u0061'`, effectively the same as point 2.
4. `System.out.println(\u0061==97);` - same as above because 97dec = 61hex except here we are not using UTF notation to represent character, instead we use numerical value of `char`
5. `\u0061='\u0041';` - `a` variable assigned value of [\u0041](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0041/index.htm) which is uppercase `A`
6. `System.out.println('A'=='\u0041');` - same as point 2
7. `System.out.println(65=='\u0041');` - 65dec = 41hex, same as point 4 but here we are comparing two constants, not the `a` variable.
8. `System.out.println(65==a);` - see above
9. `System.out.println('\u0041'==a);` - see above

Comment: "decoded into variable name during compilation" is misleading: it's decoded into the corresponding unicode symbol, `a`, which happens to be interpreted as a variable name in that specific context.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2):

> A Unicode escape of the form \uxxxx, where xxxx is a hexadecimal value, represents the UTF-16 code unit whose encoding is xxxx.

The unicode value for the character `'a'` is 97 (61 in hex), and for `'A'` is 65 (41 in hex). So the character `\u0061` in your source is read as `a`, and the character `\u0041` is read as `A`.

Your code is read as:

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        char a='a';
        System.out.println(a=='a');
        System.out.println(a=='a');
        System.out.println(a==97);
        a='A';
        System.out.println('A'=='A');
        System.out.println(65=='A');
        System.out.println(65==a);
        System.out.println('A'==a);        
    }
}
```