# Are backslashes supported in Groovy comments?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I experienced a weird Jenkins error while trying to run a groovy-scripted pipeline that contained backslashes inside comments.

Here is the offending code:

```
// The script below depends on:
// * The presence of a recent nuget.exe in c:\tools (v5.7)
// * The presence of the xxx plugin installed for user foo\username
```

I'm aware the backslash is used in many languages to start an escape sequence, but I had never before experienced backslashes being an issue inside comments.

I wonder if this *backslash in comments* behavior is due to Groovy itself or rather a bug in the way Jenkins interprets it...

**Edit:** I solved my issue by replacing the offending `\` with `\\` but then noticed I had forgotten to double the backslash in `c:\tools`, and still Jenkins did not complain. It seems Jenkins (or Groovy) tried to interpret the `\u` in `foo\username` as introducing an hex character code... but was okay with `\t` for it probably was interpreted as a tab!

Comment: The same thing applies to Java https://stackoverflow.com/a/30727799/6509 Unicode parsing happens prior to parsing the code

Comment: Then neither Groovy nor Jenkins fault, but deep in Java... Thanks! You should turn this comment into the answer!